# Curl failed to read known_hosts file

Tags: centos, scp, curl

I'm trying to download a file from a Centos 6 server using another Centos 6 server as client and `curl` with the `scp` protocol and I'm getting this error output:

```
$ curl -v -O scp://cz/path/to/file
* About to connect() to cz port 22 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4... connected
* Connected to cz (1.2.3.4) port 22 (#0)
* Failed to read known hosts from /home/cpn/.ssh/known_hosts
* SSH host check: 0, key: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAyeeDgYFsHi3Ks3PxCXt69IHBr7yNII720sXOm9WKIdGnwPf7QHbLsMf41mctcGRSJ2yO2EXpNEbZQhdUqs3oImdTn2OHF/K8STK1GXMVseusgmPuQWBt36AVPon7h9lSCjtxt+1UpFJoireXvhUDlgg9i1C9QbE04GAmA7vMOmtcVt3/3F6X/hKhOZvHj1gu5+RzCO8fXo2R8XeRoN0GcU2jVOhug0G+hXAiHymh5JzVm4YlCzsNIv3mDOF2lZRLdkor5FDKjBY8/o/5O8U0lWm4ie2S7qDppqCJP2SnNTWlaM3k5HDmdyEKKZ0lV+qG33q3ADZxjBeIKQtWLZfC3w==
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
* Using ssh public key file /home/cpn/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file /home/cpn/.ssh/id_dsa
* SSH public key authentication failed: Username/PublicKey combination invalid
* Authentication failure
* Closing connection #0
```

I can download the file using `scp` no questions asked:

```
$ scp cz:/path/to/file .
```

I can log in to the server with `ssh` again no questions asked

```
$ ssh cz
```

There are both `ssh-rsa` and `ssh-dss` keys at the server's `authorized_keys` file

What is exactly `curl` complaining about? My only guess is that `curl` wants a `dsa` key in the client's `known_hosts` file. If that is the case how to generate it? Or how to make `curl` look for the `rsa` key instead in that file?

### Update

At the client:

```
$ ls -l /home/cpn/.ssh/known_hosts
-rw-r--r--. 1 cpn cpn 1970 Nov 12 16:12 /home/cpn/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /home/cpn/.ssh/known_hosts` on the machine hosting this very file?

Comment: @John Edited with the command output

Comment: Do you expect `curl` to prompt for an SSH/SCP password, or did you configure your RSA key for this remote host? It seems like `curl` is trying to perform publickey (passwordless) authentication here.

Comment: @John I can do `scp` copy and `ssh` login using publickey for the remote host. So I expect `curl` to use publickey.

Answer (score 2):

I can at least explain what's probably going on: the `.` after the permissions in the output of `ls -l` indicates the presence of an SELinux policy, which overrides file permissions based on which program is accessing the file. Use `ls -Z ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to display the file's policy.

Presumably `/usr/bin/ssh` and its companion programs (`ssh-keygen`, `scp`, etc.) are the only programs who are allowed to access that file. I'm skeptical about this policy: it is useful to edit `~/.ssh/known_hosts` manually sometimes. However I don't understand why curl would want to read that file instead of letting `ssh` and friends do it.

You can use the [`chcon`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) command to edit the policy for that file, and [`restorecon`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/restorecon) to restore the default policy. See the [CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) for more information about SELinux.

Comment: +1 I did `setenforce 0` but still the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

For people who find this page via google:

It looks like old versions of cURL choke on `known_hosts` files with unrecognized keytypes, and sufficiently old versions of cURL don't recognize any keytype but `ssh-rsa`.

For example, my cURL is version 7.29.0 (6 years old, and the latest available in CentOS 7 as of this writing), and will cease reading keys after the first `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`, which is the majority of the keys in my `known_hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - clearing my known_hosts file made that error go away.
Not a long-term solution, but OK for a one-off workaround.